# Replacement some element with next or previous element in Scala List

Tags: scala, collections, serializable, flatmap

After knowing some function in scala, I've tried to patch the element from list:

```
val aList: List[List[Int]] = List(List(7,2,8,5,2),List(8,7,3,3,3),List(7,1,4,8,8))
```

what I want to do is replacing 8 with right neighbour element if the position of 8 is head, otherwise with left neighbour if 8 is tail.

The updated aList should be:

```
List[List[Int]] = List(List(7,2,2,5,2),List(7,7,3,3,3),List(7,1,4,4,4))
```

I've tried the following code:

```
def f(xs: List[Int]) = xs match {
  case x0 :: x1 :: x2 :: x3 :: x4 => List(x0,x1,x2,x3,x4)
  case 8 :: x1 :: x2 :: x3 :: x4 => List(x1,x1,x2,x3,x4)
  case x0 :: 8 :: x2 :: x3 :: x4 => List(x0,x0,x2,x3,x4)
  case x0 :: x1 :: 8 :: x3 :: x4 => List(x0,x1,x1,x3,x4)
  case x0 :: x1 :: x2 :: 8 :: x4 => List(x0,x1,x2,x2,x4)
  case x0 :: x1 :: x2 :: x3 :: 8 => List(x0,x1,x2,x3,x3)
}

aList.flatMap(f)
```

The type is mismatch since the type is `Product with java.io.Serializable` but requred is `scala.collection.GenTraversableOnce`

Could you please explain what is the difference and how it works?

Comment: "replacing 8 to next forward element if the position of 8 is head or with previous element if 8 is tail" - and what do you want to do if it is not first and not last? I see that you have replaced (7,2,8,5,2) -> (7,2,2,5,2) - but why did you do that? What is the rule for making that replacement? Please clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is just in the last match pattern:

```
case x0 :: x1 :: x2 :: x3 :: 8 => List(x0,x1,x2,x3,x3)
```

You put `8` in the position of the list tail, so it has to have the type `List[Int]` (or more generally `GenTraversableOnce` as the compiler tells you). If you have fixed length inner lists, you should change your patterns to have `:: Nil` in the end:

```
case 8 :: x1 :: x2 :: x3 :: x4 :: Nil => List(x1,x1,x2,x3,x4)
...
case x0 :: x1 :: x2 :: x3 :: 8 :: Nil => List(x0,x1,x2,x3,x3)
```

An alternative is

```
case List(8, x1, x2, x3, x4) => List(x1,x1,x2,x3,x4)
...
case List(x0, x1, x2, x3, 8) => List(x0,x1,x2,x3,x3)
```

Also, your first pattern means that the other ones won't be ever reached, it just leave the list as is.

If your inner lists are not necessarily fixed-size, you need a more generic solution. Clarify, please, if that's the case.

Also, if you want to map `List[List[Int]]` to `List[List[Int]]`, you should use `.map(f)` instead of `flatMap`.

#### Edit

I noticed that in your example in the last sub-list you have two `8`s replaced by the left `4`. If you want to achieve this, you can make your function recursive and add a default case (for when all `8`s are replaced).

```
def f(xs: List[Int]) = xs match {
  case 8  :: x1 :: x2 :: x3 :: x4 :: Nil => f(List(x1,x1,x2,x3,x4))
  case x0 :: 8  :: x2 :: x3 :: x4 :: Nil => f(List(x0,x0,x2,x3,x4))
  case x0 :: x1 :: 8  :: x3 :: x4 :: Nil => f(List(x0,x1,x1,x3,x4))
  case x0 :: x1 :: x2 :: 8  :: x4 :: Nil => f(List(x0,x1,x2,x2,x4))
  case x0 :: x1 :: x2 :: x3 :: 8  :: Nil => f(List(x0,x1,x2,x3,x3))
  case _ => xs
}
```

But even with these fixes this way `f` will cycle on a list with two `8`s in the beginning and some other edge cases. So here is a more generic solution with pattern matching:

```
def f(xs: List[Int]): List[Int] = {
  // if there are only 8s, there's nothing we can do
  if (xs.filter(_ != 8).isEmpty) xs
  else xs match {
    // 8 is the head => replace it with the right (non-8) neighbour and run recursion
    case 8 :: x :: tail if x != 8 => x :: f(x :: tail)
    // 8 is in the middle => replace it with the left (non-8) neighbour and run recursion
    case x :: 8 :: tail if x != 8 => x :: f(x :: tail)
    // here tail either starts with 8, or is empty
    case 8 :: tail => f(8 :: f(tail))
    case x :: tail => x :: f(tail)
    case _ => xs
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is work for me. Just realize that f will confused if there's two 8. Your logic is brilliant.

Comment: your code complete works for the logic, but I just still confused why we can't use exist(8) instead of .isEmpty?

Comment: `exists` method takes a predicate, you can say `if (!xs.exists(_ != 8)) xs else ...` instead. It's a bit shorter, but I don't like to use unary negation in `if` condition, it's kind of bug-prone.

Answer (score 1):

Works for any length of xs:

```
  def f(xs: List[Int]) = {
    if (xs.length <= 1) xs else
    (for {
      i <- 0 until xs.length
    } yield {
      xs(i) match {
        case 8 => if (i == 0) xs(1) else xs(i - 1)
        case _ => xs(i)
      }
    }).toList
  }
```

Comment: This uses non-idiomatic access of list elements by index and will fail with `IndexOutOfBoundsException` on `List(8)`

Comment: Edited to fix solution for xs.length<2